# nginx: http forward to https (works on one server, but not other!)

Tags: nginx

What I'm trying to accomplish: FORWARD `http` requests to `https`...
ie. `http://domain.com` should redirect to `https://domain.com`

I got this successfully working on one server (with different domain), but this server is failing. Going to the `http` version of the site returns a `This site can’t be reached` notice in the browser.

I'm pulling my hair out why this isn't working. Any suggestions? What should I look for, maybe other hidden settings in NGINX i'm missing?

**NOTE: The HTTPS version of the site works fine**

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name csp.domain.com;
  server_tokens off;
  return 301 https://csp.domain.com$request_uri;
}



server {
  listen       443;
  server_name  csp.domain.com;
  fastcgi_param HTTPS  on;
  ssl                  on;
  ssl_certificate      /etc/nginx/ssl/bytecp_client.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key  /etc/nginx/ssl/bytecp_client.key;
  ssl_session_timeout  5m;
  ssl_protocols  TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
  ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;

  charset                     utf-8;
  sendfile                    on;
  tcp_nopush                  on;
  tcp_nodelay                 off;
  server_tokens               off;
  reset_timedout_connection   on;

  location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|gif|png|css|js|swf|ico)$ {
      access_log      off;
      log_not_found   off;
      expires         1y;
  }

  location  /static/  {
          alias    /usr/local/kbkp-software/apps/b-nginx/usr/local/html/;
  }

  location ~ (?:/\..*|~)$ {
      access_log off;
      log_not_found off;
      deny all;
  } 
}
```

### curl Results

```
>curl -Liv http://csp.domain.com
* About to connect() to csp.domain.com port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 192.225.193.157... connected
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.22.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.22.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1 zlib/1.2.3.4 libidn/1.23 librtmp/2.3
> Host: csp.domain.com
> Accept: */*
>
* Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
* Closing connection #0
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
```

Comment: Why is there an underscore between server_name and csp.domain.com? Please edit your question to include an nslookup of the domain you want to look up plus a curl showing headers which I think is "curl -i" to demonstrate the failure.

Comment: @Tim - underscore is the catchall. probably unnecessary, removed it with same results. posted curl/nslookup results....

Comment: "Connection reset by peer" is a big clue. I think it means you can talk to the server on port 80 but there's something screwy going on. It could also mean there's a firewall in the way. Can you curl from the instance itself, as opposed to from an external workstation? Is IPTables or some other type of firewall / proxy running?

Comment: @Tim - AAHHHH good call! curl works ok from inside the box. I see the 301 Forward header. I'll check with my network admin. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

I am using universal forwarder for all domains to be forwarded to 443.

```
server {
 listen 80;
 server_name abc.domain.com efg.domain.com;
 return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```